# Como verificar si un array ya tiene el valor que le quiero agregar para poder ejecutar otra accion

Tags: javascript, array, json, reactjs

lo que necesito hacer es poder verificar si el valor que estoy intentando agregar al array ya existe para que así pueda ejecutar otra acción.

```
arrayYaExistente = [
    {
        'nombre': 'notebook',
        'precio': 199990,
        'cantidad': 1
    },
    {
        'nombre': 'celular',
        'precio': 249990,
        'cantidad': 1
    }
]

arrayParaAgregar = [
    {
        'nombre': 'notebook',
        'precio': 199990,
        'cantidad': 1
    }
]
```

La idea es que se verifique si el producto ya existe, si es así solo se debería sumar la cantidad.

Comment: Cuando dices "ya existe" te refieres al nombre? al precio? a la cantidad? a todos juntos? Esto lo puedes realizar facilmente con un `arrayYaExistente.find`

Answer (score 1):

Lo que intentas hacer es bastante simple. Lo primero que debes hacer es recorrer el array que contiene los valores a agregar, luego hacer uso del método `find()` para buscar por una propiedad de cada item del array ya existente. Si encuentra algo entonces realizas la suma de la cantidad sino simplemente haces un `push` al array para agregar el nuevo item;

Ejemplo:

```
arrayParaAgregar.forEach((item) => {
const existe = arrayYaExistente.find((x) => {
    if (x.nombre === item.nombre) {
        x.cantidad += item.cantidad;
        return x;
    }
});

if (!existe) {
    arrayYaExistente.push(item);
}
});

console.log(arrayYaExistente);
```

Answer (score 0):

Podemos buscar coincidencias dentro de un arreglo con el método `find` de javascript de la siguiente forma:

```js
arrayYaExistente = [
    {
        'nombre': 'notebook',
        'precio': 199990,
        'cantidad': 1
    },
    {
        'nombre': 'celular',
        'precio': 249990,
        'cantidad': 1
    }
]
//Con este metodo podemos buscar dentro de arreglos
ElementoEncontrado = arrayYaExistente.find(item=>{
   //Aca buscamos el producto con nombre notebook
   item.nombre == 'notebook'
})
//Aca comprobamos que hayan coincidencias
if(ElementoEncontrado){
  //Si existe notebook en el arreglo!
  console.log("El producto existe en el arreglo")
}
```

hay muchas formas de hacerlo, esta es una de ellas [Aca](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) dejo mas info del metodo `find`